# How to Perform UPSERT Operation in Arango DB with Different multiple keys (Composite Key)?

Tags: arangodb, aql

In official documentations, it's already shown how to do that. Below, an example that working fine:

**Example: 1**

```
LET documents = [
                    { name: 'Doc 1', value: 111, description: 'description 111' }, 
                    { name: 'Doc 2', value: 222, description: 'description 2' },
                    { name: 'Doc 3', value: 333, description: 'description 3' }
                ]
                    
FOR doc IN documents
    UPSERT { name: doc.name, description: doc.description }
    INSERT doc
    UPDATE doc

IN MyCollection
```

But, I want to check **different multiple keys** for **each document** on UPSERT, like:

**Example: 2**

```
LET documents = [
                    { name: 'Doc 1', value: 777, description: 'description 111' }, 
                    { name: 'Doc 2', value: 888, description: 'description 2' },
                    { name: 'Doc 3', value: 999, description: 'description 3' }
                ]
                    
FOR doc IN documents
    UPSERT {
        { name: doc.name, description: doc.description },
        { value: doc.value, description: doc.description },
        { name: doc.name, value: doc.value }
    }
    INSERT doc
    UPDATE doc

IN MyCollection
```

Or, any other other way (using filter or something). I had tried but nothing works

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Can you maybe try to explain in more detail the problem you are trying to solve with the UPSERT?

Comment: The first example is working fine for every document (row) but it has to be same KEYS for every one of them. For instance, if I make "name" and "description" columns Keys then every single document consider only these two.
However, I want to filter different keys for different document, like the try to mentioned in my second example.

Comment: Can you try to explain _the problem_ you are trying to solve? Not the way you intend to use upsert, but rather _why_ you want to use it that way?

Comment: Okay !
Suppose I've 3 documents like I had shown on my question. Now, I want to do UPSERT operation on those documents but based on different key sets.
For example, for the first document I want to be keys are "name and description", and for the second one, it will be "value and description" and for third, it should be "name and value"
How it can be done ??

Comment: This is basically your original question, just in a different wording. :) But you still did not explain the underlying problem, ie _why_ you want to do that. The UPSERT operation takes a search expression which must be an object literal without dynamic attribute names. So what you are asking for is not possible. However, if I would understand the actual problem you are trying to solve I might be able to point out other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you would want to update a document, if there's an existing one with at least 2 fields matching, otherwise insert it as new.

UPSERT won't be able to do that. It can only do one match. So a subquery is necessary. In the solution below, I ran a query to find the key of the first document that matches at least 2 fields. If there's no such document then it will return `null`.

Then the UPSERT can work by matching the `_key` to that.

```
LET documents = [
                    { name: 'Doc 1', value: 777, description: 'description 111' }, 
                    { name: 'Doc 2', value: 888, description: 'description 2' },
                    { name: 'Doc 3', value: 999, description: 'description 3' }
                ]


FOR doc IN documents
    LET matchKey= FIRST(
        FOR rec IN MyCollection
        FILTER (rec.name==doc.name) + (rec.value==doc.value) + (rec.description==doc.description) > 1
        LIMIT 1
        RETURN rec._key
    )

    UPSERT {_key:matchKey}
    INSERT doc
    UPDATE doc
    IN MyCollection
```

Note: There's a trick with adding booleans together which works because true will be converted to 1, while false is zero. You can write it out explicitly like this: `(rec.name==doc.name?1:0)`

While this will work for you it's not a very effective solution. Actually there's no effective one in this case because all the existing documents need to be scoured through to find a matching one, for each document to be added/updated. I'm not sure what kind of problem you are trying to solve with this, but it might be better to re-think your design so that the matching condition could be more simple.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a manual subquery and the implicit subquery generated for the upsert - the later observes writes performed by this query while the first one doesn't. Suppose you have two input identical input rows. If the UPSERT does not find a document for the first one it will perform an insert. For the second input the UPSERT will find the previously inserted document and therefore perform an update. The manual subquery will never observe changes performed by the query itself, but will only see a snapshot taken at the beginning of the query.